# Can Microwaves Polarize Molecular Behavior?

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to invent a microwave refrigerator. Microwave ovens are a radio signal encased with screens. If Microwaves can be polarized from right to left, can I then send a reversed signal from left to right and freeze matter? The temperature would rise and then fall greatly. I am asking for a general type answer just to know if this is worth my time as I plan to ask someone to help me make this dream come true. I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: The title and the body are different. My answer to the body, as I interpret it, is no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes microwaves can be polarized. No that can't be used to refrigerate matter. The problem (one of many) is that water molecules don't "resonate" at a specific narrow frequency, and if they are not all in phase, there is no signal you can inject to slow them down.

Contrast this with the protons (hydrogen nuclei) in an MRI experiment, where it is possible to get (a degree of) coherence between the oscillations of protons, and it is indeed possible to cause a cancellation of signals of protons oscillating with a particular frequency (this is the principle behind things like "fat suppression"). But note that even in this case, you put a lot more energy into the tissue than you take out. Entropy is not your friend...

This fridge idea is not going to work.